# how to return matrix elements indexes for its values when sorted in R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, indexing

let mymat be:

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  9.39  7.32  2.92 11.17
[2,] 10.16 12.85  3.23 10.81
[3,]  8.56  5.21 12.62 11.05
```

which is,

```
set.seed(1000)
mymat <- matrix(round(runif(12, min=1, max=15),2), nrow = 3, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

I can get the index of max and min elements of mymat using `arrayInd()`. but what I need and I do not know how to get it neatly is, getting row-col index of ALL elements of matrix from the largest element to the smallest. something like:

```
 2 2   #index for max element which is 12.85 here
 3 3   # index for next largest value
 1 4   # index for next largest value
 .
 .
 .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `melt` the `matrix` into long format `data.frame` which returns by default the row and column index as the first two column and the last column with 'value'.  Now, it is easier to `arrange` the 'value' in `desc`ending order and `select` only the index columns

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
melt(mymat) %>% 
    arrange(desc(value)) %>% 
    select(-value)
```

-output

```
    Var1 Var2
1     2    2
2     3    3
3     1    4
4     3    4
5     2    4
6     2    1
7     1    1
8     3    1
9     1    2
10    3    2
11    2    3
12    1    3
```

If the matrix have `dimnames` attributes, the `melt` returns the first columns as the row/column names.  But, if we want to remove those, then set the `dimnames` to NULL e.g.

```
dimnames(mymat) <- list(paste0("r-", 1:3), paste0("c-", 1:4))
dimnames(mymat) <- NULL
```

---

or using `base R`, create an index of the matrix elements with `order`, use to order the `row` and `col` indexes

```
i1 <- order(-mymat)
cbind(row(mymat)[i1], col(mymat)[i1])
   [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    2    2
 [2,]    3    3
 [3,]    1    4
 [4,]    3    4
 [5,]    2    4
 [6,]    2    1
 [7,]    1    1
 [8,]    3    1
 [9,]    1    2
[10,]    3    2
[11,]    2    3
[12,]    1    3
```

#### data

```
mymat <- structure(c(9.39, 10.16, 8.56, 7.32, 12.85, 5.21, 2.92, 3.23, 
12.62, 11.17, 10.81, 11.05), .Dim = 3:4)
```

Comment: I think the melt() solution is returning the name of the row and column and not the index right? I mean if my matrix had row names :r-1, r-2,... and col names : c-1, c-2, ..., this code returns r-2  c-2 . this actually happened when I tried it on such matrix.

Comment: @Mathica Yes, but I assumed that you have dimnames attributes as NULL.  If you have those attributes, makes those to `NULL` and then use `melt`

Comment: @Mathica But the second solution still works as the `row/col` are indexes